# How to save MATLAB classes to file

Tags: matlab, matlab-class

I would like to load and save some objects instantiated from a classdef style class.
I can use "save" and "load" when the objects exist in the workspace, but not outside.

For example, if I have a class called manager, that needs to load and save different employee classes, the employee classes will not exist in the workspace.

Do I need to write a custom save routine? Is there a way of leveraging the existing tools?

Comment: Does Manager contains (has) Employees as class members? or is it just a static function inside Manager?

Comment: Employee would be a class member of manager

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I hope I understand your question correctly.

You have something like this:

```
   class Manager
      properties
          Employees
      end
   end

   class Employee

   end
```

You have an instance of `Manager`

```
   manager = Manager();
   e1 = Employee();
   e2 = Employee();;
   manager.Employees{1} = e1;
   manager.Employees{2} = e2;
```

And you want to save it.

In this case, even if you don't have `e1` and `e2` in your workspace, save command will save them while saving `Manager`.

However, in order to load them correctly, you must have both `Employee` and `Manager` in your working directory. That makes sense, *because there is no other way knowing what kind of class it was*. In fact, you will get an error:

```
Warning: Variable 'manager' originally saved as a Manager cannot be instantiated as an object and will be read in as a uint32. 
Warning: Variable 'e1' originally saved as a Employee cannot be instantiated as an object and will be read in as a uint32. 
Warning: Variable 'e2' originally saved as a Employee cannot be instantiated as an object and will be read in as a uint32.
```

Comment: Thanks, but thats more of a workaround than a solution. I think i can make the question more direct:  I want to save a class that is not in the workspace. The save routine won't work, and all I can think to do is write a custom save/load routine for every class. Is there a better way?

Comment: @user1104922, not that I know of.